# Populate TreeView with data from a DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to populate a TreeView with data from a DataGridView, but I can not.

The DataGridView is with the following information:

[image: Table]

TreeView must be like below:

[image: enter image description here]]

OBS.: I created a TreeView manually to try to explain how I want it to be.

I tried to do like this:

```
    public void CarregaTreeView() {
        string pai = "";
        string filho = "";
        string noPrincipal = "";

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        noPrincipal = dgv.Rows[0].Cells["COD_PAI"].Value.ToString();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows) {
            pai = (string)row.Cells[0].Value;
            filho = (string)row.Cells[3].Value;

            if (dict.ContainsKey(pai)) {
                dict[pai].Add(filho);
            }
            else {
                dict.Add(pai, new List<string>());
                dict[pai].Add(filho);
            }

        }
        //adicionar nó principal
        TreeNode objTopNode = new TreeNode(noPrincipal + " - DESCRICAO - [QTDE]");
        tv.Nodes.Add(objTopNode);
        objTopNode.Tag = noPrincipal;

        MontaTreeView(dict, objTopNode);
    }

    private void MontaTreeView(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict, TreeNode objparentNode) {

        foreach (var kvp in dict) {

            objcurrentNode = new TreeNode(kvp.Key + " - DESCRICAO - [QTDE]");
            objparentNode.Nodes.Add(objcurrentNode);
            objcurrentNode.Tag = kvp.Key;
            objcurrentNode.Expand();

            if (kvp.Key.Contains("T")) {
                Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
                dict1.Add(kvp.Key, new List<string>());
                dict1[kvp.Key].Add(dict[kvp.Key][0]);
                MontaTreeView(dict1, objcurrentNode);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: is this win forms?

Comment: @Marcelo I'm sorry, but in the current form the question is very hard to answer. Can you possibly remove extra bits of code that is not related, show us your data as text, not as image and show us what you get as an output from your code and what exactly does not work there?

Comment: @Marcelo A lot of times while you try to simplify the question, you actually get your answer yourself. So this is worth doing

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to iterate over your grid view. For each row, find its parent node in the tree, then add the row to the node children.

```
TreeNode findParent(string txt, TreeNode parent = null)
{
   if (parent == null)
     parent = treeView1.Nodes[0];
   if (parent.Text == txt) return parent;
   foreach (TreeNode node in parent.Children)
   {
      var res = findParent(txt, node); //recursion
      if (res != null) return res;
   }
   return null;
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    TreeNode parent = findParent(row.Cells[2].Value as string);
    var newNode = new TreeNode() { Text = row.Cells[0].Value as Text };
    if (parent != null)
       parent.Children.Add(newNode);
    else
       treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Kilanny!

Comment: @Marcelo Glad to help. Please mark the answer as your "best" answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!